# when i am upload my project to online mode, in login TokenMismatchException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vps

(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
 In laravel in my local is run normally but if my project upload to Webuzo is error

Answer (score 0):

Are you going from http to https? You may have to enable secure session cookies.